# XML in an XML Documentation Comment (C#)

Tags: c#, .net

How can I embed XML in an C# XML documentation comment (e.g. in an header of a method)?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Put it in a CDATA section, and put the CDATA section inside a `<code>` element so it will be formatted correctly:

```
/// <example>
/// <code>
/// <![CDATA[ 
/// <someXml>
///     ...
/// </someXml>
/// ]]>
/// </code>
/// </example>
```

Answer (score 0):

Press '/' (slash) 3 times in the code file and it will open a code summary section. You can paste your xml on that section.